# Metro App XAML Data Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, microsoft-metro

I am new to XAML and metro app development & have just started building very basic windows store applications.

I am having problem in understanding the XAML binding process, how the XAML binding takes place.

Please help me.

Comment: Its can be more clear if you provide some your code. Or want you to have some links to read about binding in XAML based application?

Answer (score 0):

Bindings in `XAML` is the big theme. In two word: you shoud set `DataContext` or `DataSource` for you control like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    Foreground="Black" FontSize="30" Height="50" Width="780"/>
</Grid>
```

In you code write:

```
public class Recording 
{
  public string Artist { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<Recording> MyMusic = new ObservableCollection<Recording>();
MyMusic.Add(new Recording("Chris Sells", "Chris Sells Live",
    new DateTime(2008, 2, 5)));
MyMusic.Add(new Recording("Luka Abrus",
    "The Road to Redmond", new DateTime(2007, 4, 3)));
MyMusic.Add(new Recording("Jim Hance",
    "The Best of Jim Hance", new DateTime(2007, 2, 6)));

// Set the data context for the combo box.
ComboBox1.DataContext = MyMusic;
```

More about bindings you can find in [Data binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh758320.aspx) and [Quickstart: Data binding to controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh464965.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

***Data Binding Window Store App:-***
Consider a scenario in which you are having a JSON file and you have written name's of customer. Now shop keeper have asked you to fetch all name's. Instead of going through all of name (txt file) just simply bind all name's show it.

First of all what you need?
 1. A text file/ Data.
 2. A class which tells about your contracts.
3. A databinding coding.

I've created a Data.txt file in Assets Folder.

```
 [
 {"Name" : "Google" , "Surname" : "Inc."},
 {"Name" : "Stack" , "Surname" : "overflow"}
 ]
```

2. Step: I have created a class. myData

```
 [DataContract]
class myData {
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

}
```

Here [DataContract] represents that you're signing a contract and sending to
client which is your system (just for understanding purpose).

Step 3: Now I've created a method with name loadData() which will get all names.

```
 public async void loadData() {
        ObservableCollection<string> n = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        StorageFile sf = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\Data.txt");
        var data = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sf);
        DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<myData>));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
        List<myData> nm = (List<myData>)json.ReadObject(ms);
        foreach (var item in nm)
        {
            n.Add(item.Name);

        }
        names.DataContext = n;

    }
```

And Now I've invoked this loadData() method on Submit/button click.
I hope now it becomes clear to you :).
Thanks & Regards,